# Can I invoke an ancestor's method from a child's overloaded method?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to design my (Java) classes and I am not sure what this is called-- essential it goes something like this:

```
MediaPlayer // contains play(String filePath) method

OtherPlayer // extends MediaPlayer and inherits play(String filePath) 

MyObject  // extends OtherPlayer
```

The problem is-- I want `MyObject` to call play without passing the string in. `MyObject` contains a private member and I want to simply call,

```
myobject.play();
```

Can I have MyObject overload `play()` but somehow call `play(String filePath)` using its private string?

Edit:

I want to avoid doing this:

```
myobject.play(myobject.getFilePath());
```

Comment: Is play declared in any of the ancestors?

Comment: play(String filePath) is in all other ancestors, but there is no play()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `play(String)` is public/protected, then simply:

```
class MyObject extends OtherPlayer {
    ...

    public void play() {
        play(myString);
    }

    private String myString;
}
```

Comment: So even though the new play() overloads the old play, the old play(string name) is still valid? Gah I feel dumb!

Comment: Dont' feel dumb @Google you have all the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like

```
class MyObject extends OtherPlayer {

    private String myString;

    public void play(){
       play( myString );
    }

}
```

Then that's perfectly fine. You won't be *overloading* `play()` though, just creating a new method (different signatures means different methods).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void play() {
    super.play(myfilename); // calls the inherited method
}

private someMethod() {
    play(); // call your method like this
}
```